# What is the best way/method to digitize the data of a 3D surface into a grid of pixels with smaller resolution in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, physics, resolution

I want to digitize (= average out over cells) photon count data into pixels given by a grid that tells how they are aligned. The photon count data is stored in a 2D array. I want to split that data into cells, each of which would correspond to a pixel. The idea is basically the same as changing an HD image to a smaller resolution. I'd like to achieve this in Python.

The digitizing function I've written:

```
import numpy as np

def digitize(function_data, grid_shape):
    """
    function_data = 2D array of function values of some 3D shape, 
    eg.: exp(-(x^2 + y^2 -> want to digitize this
    grid_shape: an array of length 2 which contains the dimensions of the smaller resolution 
    """
    l = len(function_data)
    pixel_len_x = int(l/grid_shape[0])
    pixel_len_y = int(l/grid_shape[1])
    digitized_data = np.empty((grid_shape[0], grid_shape[1]))

    for i in range(grid_shape[0]): #row-index of pixel in smaller-resolution grid
        for j in range(grid_shape[1]): #column-index of pixel in smaller-resolution grid
            hd_pixel = [] 
            for k in range(pixel_len_y):
                hd_pixel.append(z_data[k][j:j*pixel_len_x])
            hd_pixel = np.ravel(hd_pixel) #turns 2D array into 1D to be able to compute average
            pixel_avg = np.average(hd_pixel)
            digitized_data[i][j] = pixel_avg

    return digitized_data
```

In theory, this function should do what I want to achieve, but when tested it doesn't yield the expected results. Either a completed version of my function or any other method that achieves my goal would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a interpolation function, if you can use SciPy. Here we use one of the gridded data interpolating functions, [`RectBivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline) to upsample your function, but you can find numerous examples on this and other sites.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline as rbs

# Sampling coordinates
x = np.linspace(-2,2,20)
y = np.linspace(-2,2,30)
# Your function
f = np.exp(-(x[:,None]**2 + y**2))
# Interpolator
interp = rbs(x, y, f)
# Higher resolution coordinates
x_hd = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), x.size * 5)
y_hd = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), y.size * 5)
# New higher res function
f_hd = interp(x_hd, y_hd, grid = True)
# Some plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 2)
ax[0].imshow(f)
ax[1].imshow(f_hd)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use reverse interpolation

Comment: if the proposed solution satisfies.. u may click on the tick to mark the question as 'answered'.  ( :